# Nearby message api error - Nearby.Messages is not enabled for this app: packageName

Tags: android, eddystone, google-nearby

I am trying to use the nearby message api to get message from a eddystone beacon. I have followed the following documentation :

[https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/overview?hl=en][1]

I am using the SHA1 from the default debug keystore. But I keep getting the following error message

```
 Nearby.Messages is not enabled for this app: packageName
```

Device : Nexus 6 (Android version 5.1.1)

Play services version : 8.1.15

Comment: Can you add some information about your device? What version of Google Play Services are you using?

Comment: @ShailenTuli I have updated the post with device and play services version

Comment: It's hard to know without more context why you're getting the message. Can you build and run the NearbyDevices sample from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-nearby?  Follow the instructions in the README for setting up the key in the manifest, etc. Modify the subscription method Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, mMessageListener, PUB_SUB_STRATEGY) to Nearby.Messages.subscribe(mGoogleApiClient, messageListener, Strategy.BLE_ONLY). Let me know if that works.

Comment: I have tried that sample earlier and tried debugging it , I get the same error . Even though  I replaced the api key. Is it something to do with the keystore. I use the default debug keystore of android studio.

Comment: Find the apk generated, and use `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile {something}.apk | grep SHA1` to get the SHA. Then follow the instructions in the README.

Comment: seems its the right SHA1 , I am getting the following error message in onResult() of ResultCallback : Nearby.Messages is not enabled for this app: packageName

Comment: I just cloned the sample and ran it successfully. Perhaps you can post your log output?

Answer (score 3):

You're getting this error because you didn't explicitly ask user for permissions, which you **must** do in order to use the Nearby API. Here's one way to do this:

```
// GoogleApiClient connection callback. Initiate permission check here.
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Nearby.Messages.getPermissionStatus(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ErrorCheckingCallback("getPermissionStatus", new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    publishAndSubscribe();
                }
            })
    );
}


// This is called in response to a button tap in the Nearby permission dialog.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
        mResolvingError = false;
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Permission granted or error resolved successfully then we proceed
            // with publish or subscribe..
            publishAndSubscribe();
        } else {
            // This may mean that user had rejected to grant nearby permission.
            showToast("Failed to resolve error with code " + resultCode);
        }
    }
}


/**
* A simple ResultCallback that displays a toast when errors occur.
* It also displays the Nearby opt-in dialog when necessary.
*/
private class ErrorCheckingCallback implements ResultCallback<Status> {
   private final String method;
   private final Runnable runOnSuccess;

   private ErrorCheckingCallback(String method) {
       this(method, null);
   }

   private ErrorCheckingCallback(String method, @Nullable Runnable runOnSuccess) {
       this.method = method;
       this.runOnSuccess = runOnSuccess;
   }

   @Override
   public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
       if (status.isSuccess()) {
           Log.i(TAG, method + " succeeded.");
           if (runOnSuccess != null) {
               runOnSuccess.run();
           }
       } else {
           // Currently, the only resolvable error is that the device is not opted
           // in to Nearby. Starting the resolution displays an opt-in dialog.
           if (status.hasResolution()) {
               if (!mResolvingError) {
                   try {
                       status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                               REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
                       mResolvingError = true;
                   } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                       showToastAndLog(Log.ERROR, method + " failed with exception: " + e);
                   }
               } else {
                   // This will be encountered on initial startup because we do
                   // both publish and subscribe together.  So having a toast while
                   // resolving dialog is in progress is confusing, so just log it.
                   Log.i(TAG, method + " failed with status: " + status
                           + " while resolving error.");
               }
           } else {
               showToastAndLog(Log.ERROR, method + " failed with : " + status
                       + " resolving error: " + mResolvingError);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

You can find a complete example [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/pub-sub).

Also, remember about the [guidelines](https://developers.google.com/nearby/developer-guidelines):

- > Don’t surprise the user. Require the user to perform an explicit
  >   action (a button tap, going to a section in your app, a special
  >   switch, etc) to activate Nearby.
- > On both iOS and Android, calling
  >   Nearby for the first time will trigger a permission dialog. Waiting
  >   for an explicit user action before invoking Nearby will help the user
  >   contextualize the dialog and associate it with your app's
  >   proximity-based feature.

Comment: minor change, I think it should be "status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,ConnectionResult.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED);" I couldn't find "REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR"

Comment: @tallen It's just a so-called "request code", a random constant defined by you. It can be any integer. See http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html for more info.

Comment: This is, more or less, correct. I found the way they did the callback class (with the runnable) to be needlessly convoluted, or maybe I'm just not that smart, I haven't decided. At run-time you wind up getting called back twice because you are implicitly asking for two permissions(this is the wrong word, opt-in maybe be better). The call to startResolutionForResult pops up an activity that asks for the permissions . These permissions (opt-ins) are not to be confused with the stuff you do in the manifest, it's a GooglePlayServicesAPI thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly ask user for permission to use Nearby. The Nearby API now provides shortcut for code provided by [EyesClear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33027365/7001521). You just need to call [enableAutoManage](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder#enableAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)) method on API client builder.

Look for details at: https://developers.google.com/nearby/messages/android/user-consent

Unfortunately this can work only for foreground subscriptions.